# How long is Goku's pole?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Whats the maxium extent Goku has ever extended the power pole in the series? He uses it a lot in the series to do various lengths but do we know a maximum length, or the farthest hes ever extended it?

[image: Goku holding his power pole]

Comment: Don't think I didn't see that. You edit that title right back, mister.

Comment: @GGMG but i think its perfect :P

Comment: Man this question sounds dirty.

Comment: Should this be in Anime Stackexchange?

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari all fantasy sci-fi anime are on topic here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the farthest the stick has extended in DragonBall is the distance between the Earth and the Moon.

In DragonBall chapter 17, Goku fights a gang of rabbits whose Boss can transform people into carrots. Once they are defeated, he decides to take them far away, very far... directly to the moon.

**So : 384.400Km or 238,855 miles approximatively (if the distance Earth-moon is the same in Dragon Ball than in the real world)**

[image]
[image]

Reference : http://thedaoofdragonball.com/blog/dragon-world/dragon-ball-white-rabbit-moon/

Comment: Sorry liesmith, I didn't see your comment before writing my post... You were right I think

Comment: +1 if the distance Earth-moon is the same in Dragon Ball than in the real world. We never see the pole getting longer in the manga, but we can suppose that it could be even longer if the user wants it.

Answer (score 8):

Goku of dragonball was inspired from The Monkey King from 16th century Chinese classical novel The Journey to the West.

The staff first appears in the third chapter when the Monkey King, Sun Wukong, goes to the underwater kingdom of Ao Guang, the Dragon King of the East Sea, looking for a magic weapon to match his strength and skill.

Upon Sun Wukong's approach, the staff glows to signify it has found its true master.

The staff is initially described as a pillar of black iron twenty feet in height and the width of a barrel.

It is only when Monkey lifts it and suggests that a smaller size would be more manageable that the staff complies with his wishes and shrinks. The inscription on the staff indicates that it follows the commands of its owner, shrinking or growing to their whim, make copies of itself.

Since it is magical and can grow and shrink according the command of its owner, I assume it can reach any length that its owner wishes.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that he extended it to the moon one time in Dragonball (to deal with an anthropomorphic rabbit, obviously).

Comment: The problem is that Dragonball *isn't* The Journey to the West, and the stories are quite different in many respects. This answer might be good if there are no canon answers relating to the show itself, but then the answer should mention that.

Comment: I understand its different but Akira Toriyama explicitly stated that he took inspiration from The Journey to the west. Goku was The Monkey King, and his pole is the staff. Goku's quest to find the dragon ball is similar to The Monkey King's quest to find the sutras. The Monkey King travels on his cloud, so does Goku travel on his nimbus cloud.

Comment: The Pole is magical, hence it can reach any length that its owner wishes.

Comment: @j4rey89 The Monkey King doesn't travel on a cloud.

Comment: The Flying Nimbus is one of the two items that Goku possessed that mimics the character Sun Wukong in the Chinese novel Journey to the West. Sun Wukong rides on a magic cloud, and the other is the Power Pole, which Sun Wukong also uses. ..........check dragonball wikia http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Nimbus

Comment: @j4rey89 Interesting. In the version I read he rolled through the clouds.